# Single Touch Rotation Using Clip

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, uibezierpath

I would like to rotate an image by using the rotation point and single touch. Can you please any one help me to do this?

[image: Rotate_Image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417820/iphone-ios-how-to-create-interactive-drag-rotate-resize-delete-view-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi have a look on this once....

[Touch rotate image](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tdresizerview)

[SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417820/iphone-ios-how-to-create-interactive-drag-rotate-resize-delete-view-control)